# Scala CSV-like data source to flat json representation

Tags: json, scala

I've been searching for how to flatten a JSON representation of a given data in a CSV file.

Let's say the CSV is in the form:

```
headerFieldName_1, ... headerFieldName_n,
value_1.1, ... , value_1.n
value_2.1, ... , value_2.n
...
value_m.1, ... , value_m.n
```

Now, the flat JSON I'd like to get is the following:

```
[ {headerFieldName_1 : value_1.1, ... , headerFieldName_n : value_1.n},
  {headerFieldName_1 : value2.1, ... , headerFieldName_n : value_2.n},
...
  {headerFieldName_1 : value_m.1, ... , headerFieldName_n : value_m.n},
]
```

Since every element in the array is a JSON object with custom presentation, I think there is no convenient `JsValue` to use.

I think using `Format[x]` is not useful in this case, since it is helpful only to map arrays of key / value pairs. So maybe some custom `Reads` and `Writes` will be more suitable for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no on-line for this if that is what you are looking for, but implementing it is very straightforward. Assuming your file is not too big (else JSON is a terrible format to use), you need to:

1. Read the file contents: `scala.io.Source.fromFile("your path").getLines`
2. Process the first line to get headers (keys). Use `line.split(",")` to get separate fields.
3. Process each remaining line, assemble a JSON object with all the known keys and the values for that line.
4. Append all the objects so created to a JsArray.